# MySQL max_user_connections limit still allows incoming connections

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I have a MySQL Server 5.1 installed on one of my Ubuntu machines. I have a user 'john' for whom I've set the max_user_connections to '4' which means this user can have only 4 simultaneous connections. I made 3 and it shall take only one connection from this user. But I see there are lot of incoming connections from this user.

After updating the limit, I've run "flush privileges;" too. So, this shouldn't happen. Why this is happening?